# How to represent sentense as a numarical vector while keeping the order of each word relative to other words For Classificaion Algorithms..

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, feature-extraction, nlp-question-answering

I am creating a sentence classification program for my Final year project. My goal is to classify question in to 10 classes according to the expected answer. I need to represent question in a vector while keeping the order of words.

**Conciser this example**

- can i order a pizza
- i can order a pizza

above two sentences  have the same word vector when represented in bag of words or bag  of feature representations. Is there any other representation technique to represent question.
that way classifier can be told that word 'i' is before 'can' so they can be classified differently.

Please note that this is not a matter of classifying question and sentences. i have to classify questions into fields based not only on the expected answer but also some other keywords as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Natural Language Processing** you have basically **2 ways** of representing a sentence:

- [Bag of Words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) (most of the time called "BoW")
- [Word Vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding) (or Word Embeddings)

The first one (*Machine Learning approach*) gives you a sparse vector and the latter (*Deep Learning approach*) a dense vector.

If you're willing to go with BoW you basically throwing any order in the sentence, because the vector is composed of every word found in the text.

```
pizza / can / a / order / i
```

Sentence 1 : `[1,1,1,1,1]`

Sentence 2 : `[1,1,1,1,1]`

The 2 sentences will have the same representation using [unigram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) but with [bigram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) that will change because in addition to words you'll have all combinations of 2 words also.

```
pizza / can / a / order / i / can i / i order / order a / a pizza / i can / can order
```

Sentence 1 : `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]`

Sentence 2 : `[1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1]`

See [this article](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html) and specifically the [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer) in order to solve your problem.

Comment: I really appreciate your reply. I am using bi-grams to identify certain phrases in the question (ex :- names of a diseases) I will try this and let you know. To be honest i never thought of this type of a bi-gram vector for BOW.  Thanks a lot.